# Parse text file line by line using split

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, streamreader

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
Name    : <John Doe> First field in group
Rank    : <Private>
DOB     : <1/25/92>
etc
etc
etc
55 more fields
Retired : <Y>   Last field in group
```

Part 2 looks simular to:

```
Additional Data 1
   field 1  : <some data>
   field 2  : <more data>
   field 3  : <still more data>
Additional Data 2
   field 1  : <some data>
   field 2  : <more data>
   field 3  : <still more data>
Additional Data 3
   field 1  : <some data>
   field 2  : <more data>
   field 3  : <still more data>
.... up to 10 groups of additional data
```

I am using a StreamReader to read the file, no issues there
I am using the split function to pull out the field name and field values, no issues there. 
I have 61 fields on my form their names are fld_1, fld_2, fld_3 etc
My problem is trying to populate my form with each value and stopping at the last field "Retired"

I've tried using a StreamReader and split, its the taking the fieldValue and putting it in the appropriate text box on my form.

```
    Public Sub reader()
       Dim x as Interger = 1  
       Using objReader as New StreamReader("C:\temp\testFile.txt")
          Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
             Dim line As String = objReader.ReadLine()
             If line.Contains(":") Then
                Dim splitLine() as String = line.Split(":")

                Dim fieldName as String = splitLine(0)
                Dim fieldValue as String = splitLine(1)

                Dim txtBox as TextBox
                Dim name As String = "fld_" * x.ToString
                txtBox = Controls.Item(name)
                txtBox.Text = fieldValue

             If Not objReader.EndOfStream then
                line = objReader.ReadLine
             End If
          End If
          x = x + 1
        Loop
       End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You mentioned an error. What error is that, and do you know where in your code it is being triggered? As it stands, it's a little hard to find exactly what you're asking in your question.

Comment: Do you intend to process only every other line?  You have two `objReader.ReadLine` in the code.

Comment: No that is not my intent, I want to find the start field "Name" and parsing until it gets to the end field "Retired"

Comment: The description of the file structure should be more percise. Do you have other lines before the one that starts with `name`? Are there other lines after the `Retired` one? What separates the *field* name from its value? Are those spaces or `TABs`? Can you use a DataGridView (or a ListView) to present the data, instead of a bunch of `Textboxes`? Are users allowed to edit the data and save the changes (this affects the way those lines of text are handled)? Add the details that can help people help you.

Comment: Other than some blank lines at the top of the file, there will only be one instance of the record starting with the Name and ending with Retired. the : seperates the fieldName from the fieldValue, The format of the file has not changed in 10 years, so I am not worried about it changing, there are 61 feilds that make up a record, my field names on the form are fld_1, fld_2, fld_3...fId_61. I was thinking i could do a for loop that each time it goes through the loop it would grab the fieldValue and plop it into the approriate form field.

Comment: The standard method for files with a delimiter is to use [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.8) . I tested with your file and it works fine with ":" as separator.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually inspecting the content of the lines read from the file.
The record's starting line contains **`Name`**, the last one contain **`Retired`**. Let's look for these strings and perform the required actions when found.

I think this was a typo; trying to multiply strings is not that useful:

```
Dim name As String = "fld_" * x.ToString
```

Initialize a [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader) with a [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement: this object needs to be disposed of.
Start a loop that reads lines of text until the start of a record is found or the StremReader reaches the end of the file; in this case, exit the procedure.

Then, keep reading lines of text until a line that [StartsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith) `Retired` is found.

```
Private Sub fileReader(filePath as String)
    Dim comp = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
    Dim lineContent As String = String.Empty
    Dim line As Integer = 1

    Using reader = New StreamReader(filePath)
        Do
            lineContent = reader.ReadLine
        Loop While Not (reader.EndOfStream OrElse lineContent.StartsWith("Name", comp))
        If reader.EndOfStream Then Return
        Controls($"fld_{line}").Text = lineContent.Split(":"c)(1).Trim()

        While Not lineContent.StartsWith("Retired", comp)
            line += 1
            lineContent = reader.ReadLine
            Controls($"fld_{line}").Text = lineContent.Split(":"c)(1).Trim()
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

This line of code uses string interpolation:

```
Controls($"fld_{line}").Text = ...
```

In your VB.Net version doesn't allow it, use `string.Format()`:

```
Controls(String.Format("fld_{0}", line)).Text = ...
```

Comment: I'm getting tripped up here: Controls(String.Format("fld_{0}",line)).Text = lineContent I get NullReferenceException...Object reference not set...line = 1 and lineContent = "John doe"

Comment: I inserted a generic name. Now replaced with the one you provided.

Comment: Thanks Sir I had caught that and changed mine to fld_ I still get the error after making the change.

Comment: What is the name of your TextBoxes then? Are these controls child of the Form, or you put them inside a Panel or other container? If so, you need to use the container's collection. e,g. `Panel1.Controls(...)`

Comment: I just double checked, all my field names are indeed fld_1 ..  fld_61, ah, my text boxes are on TabControl1. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: I have the main string parsing into a datatable perfectly, part 2 is that there several subfields that are formatt something like this after "Retired"

Comment: I can parse the first group of Additional data, but not sure how to get it to loop through the rest of the Addiitional data groups in the file.